# Play back MOV in WPF

Tags: wpf, quicktime

I know this has been asked before, but the answer seemed incomplete...

Is there a way to playback .mov files in the MediaElement control in WPF, or what's the alternative? Has anyone done it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [QT Lite](http://codecguide.com/qt_lite.htm). It installs the necessary Directshow filters for playback. You may need additional filters depending on what video codec is used inside the MOV container. [FFDShow-Tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) may help you if that is the case.